# How can I get MenuStrip work when its parent form is embedded in another application

Tags: c#, winforms

Now that i have a WinFormApp with MenuStrip called "TargetForm", and it's embedded in another WinFormApp which's "HostForm", by calling the API function SetParent. But i found the MenuStrip cease to function no matter how i click on it

Seems that the TargetForm's MenuStrip has not realized that the mouse has been click when it was hosted by HostForm.

I'm using SPY++ to monitor the Windows messages on the TargetForm, and found WM_PARENTNOTIFY was raised when i click on the menu

Is it possible that i can post the Windows message WM_PARENTNOTIFY to the MenuStrip from HostForm?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the contents of the main form of the embedded app into a WinForms User Control (put it into a separate project), and embed the user control into both applications.

Comment: But my problem is that I cannot click the menu when it's embedded into another app